# Visual Studio 2019 Automatic Event Handlers Generation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets

Is it at all possible to generate handlers for ALL events object has to offer in a similar way you can do it for a single event simply by pressing tab tab after += ?

if not Visual Studio, any other IDE that can do that ?

Comment: What specific usage do you have in mind? In my experience classes would either have a few events, and then registering handlers one by one is not much work, or you have many events, and then you are probably only interested in a few of them.

Comment: Not all events perform the same code.  So you would need to be able to in the event handler be able to specify which code to run.  So a parameter would be need to indicate what type of event we being performed by the handler.

Comment: @JonasH well the one I am working with has 20+ events each. Use case is simple code testing if not for implementation.

Comment: @ArkadiuszRycyk this doesn't explain anything. You don't need event handlers for code you don't intend to test. Just generating an empty handler won't help you test anything - but it will help *cheat* coverage tools by displaying fake 100% coverage. If you want to test that all events are fired (is that really the case?) you can use reflection to add link the same event handler to multiple events (provided the signatures match)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Post your code and clearly explain the problem. You may be able to use Reflection to get all events with [Type.GetEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getevents?view=net-6.0#system-type-getevents) and attach a handler to all of them as shown in [How to: Hook Up a Delegate Using Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-hook-up-a-delegate-using-reflection)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am asking about the tool what does it matter what the code is.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Class.myevent += (here tab tab and Visual Studio generates handler automatically). T

Answer (score 1):

I have one way for you. Obviously, this solution will not meet your needs i 100%, but you can try it.
You can create an interface with all methods from a known object and inherit it. Now you can implement this interface. Unfortunately, you need to add an event handler to the constructor.

```
class myObject:IMyObject {

    Public myObject() //this you have to add
    {
        this.my_Event += onMy_EventHandled();
        this.my_Event1 += onMy_EventHandled1();
    }

    //this section will be create automatically        
    void onMy_EventHandled()
    {
    }
        
    void onMy_EventHandled2()
    {
    }
}
```

e.g. interface

```
interface IMyObject {
   void onMy_EventHandled();
   void onMy_EventHandled();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this will only add more work I think. Aim is to do less manual work :). Anyway, thanks for your suggestion.